# SQL to insert millions of dummy records into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that I'd like to test the performance of. I want to insert approximately 5 million records into a table with an auto-incremented primary key. Is there an easy way to do this quickly with SQL? I know I can pipe in a .sql file, but all I really want to do is insert the same identical data (but with a different PK), 5 million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert NULL as the value of the PK or just simply don't specify it in the columns list in your insert statement. That way it gets auto incremented.

```
for ($i=0; $i<5000000; $i++) {
    "INSERT INTO table (id,name) values (NULL,'somename')"; // obviously in form of $dbh->() something
}
```

Comment: This doesn't tell me how I would do this 5 million times though.

Comment: More that, it will be broken down at timeout!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a good performance test, as identical rows will not create indicies with regularly distributed values for anything but the PK, so most queries will not demonstrate expected performance.

I would consider using a test data generation tool like Faker (ruby and perl varieties exist):

http://faker.rubyforge.org/